# SCSS How to change order of rendering included mixins

Tags: sass

This is a hard question, so I am aware that no one may come up with solution, but that's the problem I really need to solve in my framework.

I have a `screen()` mixin written in SCSS, which takes `$size` as an argument, to return any `@content` wrapped in a media query.

The problem occurs when one element `@include`s multiple screen() mixins, because resulting media queries will overwrite each other in the same order as they were included. How can I make sure the resulting media queries will be rendered in the correct order (biggest screen to smallest), even if I forget to include them in the right order?

http://sassmeister.com/gist/951520fa83d1e1c69c9d

```
@mixin screen(
  $size: null
){
  @if $size == md {
    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @if $size == sm {
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @if $size == xs {
    @media (max-width: 320px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

/* output should be 1024, 768, 320 */

.screen {
  &:before {
    // this should be included as the Last one
    @include screen(xs){
      content: "xs";
    }

    @include screen(sm){
      content: "sm";
    }

    // this should be included as the First one
    @include screen(md){
      content: "md";
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to solve that issue by creating placeholder selectors in the right order `%media-sm{...}`, `%media-xs {...}`..., and `@extend` them from the mixin, but `@content` can't be passed through the `@extend` directive.

Another solution is a hard one - create an array of keys - sizes, and values - `@contents` and render them from another function.

Comment: The `@extend` directive works with `@content` just fine, it just doesn't work with media queries the way you're trying to use them.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Sass only does exactly what you tell it to do.  If you want your styles to appear in a specific order, write them in that specific order.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to pass in the media width you are trying to target:

```
@mixin media($width) {
  @media only screen and (max-width: $width) {
    @content;
  }
}

@include media(320px) {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: That still won't do what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I'm going to support both size as a number or keyword, but yeah, that was not what the question is about.